# Compare attribute with number literal

Tags: jmespath

I am trying to find all VMs with exactly 2 cores:

```
$ az vm list-sizes -o json --query "[?numberOfCores == 2]"
az vm list-sizes: error: argument --query: invalid query value: '[?numberOfCores == 2]'
```

As I suspected an error with the `az` command, I installed [jp directly](https://github.com/jmespath/jp), but it also gives an error:

```
$ az vm list-sizes -o json | jp "[?numberOfCores == 2]"
SyntaxError: Invalid token: tNumber
[?numberOfCores == 2]
```

In [the jmespath specification](http://jmespath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/proposals/filter-expressions.html#specification) it looks like I have to use the backtick `` ` `` character, but instead of an error it just gives no results:

```
$ az vm list-sizes -o json | jp '[?numberOfCores == `2`]'
[]
```

This is the (abbreviated) returned json I'm trying to filter:

```
$ az vm list-sizes -o json | head -n 20
[
  {
    "maxDataDiskCount": 4,
    "memoryInMb": 123,
    "name": "Standard_DS1",
    "numberOfCores": 1,
    "osDiskSizeInMb": 456,
    "resourceDiskSizeInMb": 789
  },
  {
    "maxDataDiskCount": 8,
    "memoryInMb": 123,
    "name": "Standard_DS2",
    "numberOfCores": 2,
    "osDiskSizeInMb": 456,
    "resourceDiskSizeInMb": 789
  }
]
```

<sup>(I obfuscated the sizes because I don't want to be sued by MS for sharing trade secrets or something)</sup>

Comment: This seems to work now: az vm list-sizes -l swedenCentral --query '[?numberOfCores == `2`]'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JMESPath query is correct, but there was an issue with the way the homebrew version of `jp` was built (it was using an outdated script for building the `jp` binary).  Now the homebrew installed version of `jp` will always used the signed release binaries from https://github.com/jmespath/jp/releases.  These binaries are tested on every commit.  You should be able to `brew update && brew upgrade jp`, or use a binary from https://github.com/jmespath/jp/releases if you're not using homebrew.

Comment: I updated my `jp` and it's working now. That's not the first place where I would have looked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi jamesls, I'm wondering why the jmespath need to use the backtick '\`' character for number literals -- e.g., what would the `"[?numberOfCores == 2]"` be interpreted if not comparing `numberOfCores` to exactly 2 cores? what would jmespath think that "2" is? thx

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was using **double quotes** with --query flag while executing [office365 cli](https://pnp.github.io/cli-microsoft365/) command same as **@user3151902** is using . 
 **Note::** Double quotes worked with the string values but throws error with number values.

**Wrong Way::**

```
m365 spo list list -o json --query "[?BaseTemplate==`100`]" -u https://{contoso}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteName}
```

**Right Way::**

```
m365 spo list list -o json --query '[?BaseTemplate==`100`]' -u https://{contoso}.sharepoint.com/sites/{siteName}
```